# How to determine if the caller has permissions to edit a OneDrive file using MSGraph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

What is the correct way to determine a file’s access permissions on OneDrive when using MSGraph API? Specifically, how can I tell if the caller can edit the file?

I used the [list permissions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and I get a collection of [permission objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0). The docs state that:

> The permissions collection includes potentially sensitive information and may not be available for every caller.
>
> - For the owner of the item, all sharing permissions will be returned. This includes co-owners.
> - For a non-owner caller, only the sharing permissions that apply to the caller are returned.
> - Sharing permission properties that contain secrets (e.g. shareId and webUrl) are only returned for callers that are able to create the sharing permission.

I tried to list the permissions on an item that was shared with the caller and the list I got included `grantedTo` entries for other users than the calling user despite what the docs say. Actually, no `grantedTo` entry was specified for the user I was calling with. The list also included a `link` permission entry. Can I assume that entry applies to the calling user?

I couldn’t find anything in the docs that explains how to use the list to know whether the user has read or write access to the file.

Should I iterate the list and look for `grantedBy` entries that match the current user’s id? Should I look at the `link` entries’ roles too? If there is such an entry with a `write` role, does that mean I can upload a new version of that file?

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity yes please

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity do you have any info that can help figure this out? Thanks!